# Circle below graph on matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, networkx

Any help with this question is appreciated.

I have written the following code using matplotlib plot a graph and some circles on the same axes.

```
import sys,os,re
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Circle

class GraphForPlot:
  def __init__(self):
    self.G = nx.Graph()
    self.Components = []
    self.ActiveStatus = {}
    self.Nodes = []
    self.Position = {}
    self.Color = []
    self.p = {}
```

And in the main function I have the following

```
fig, PlotAxes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
plt.tight_layout()
for i in range(0, len(GPlot)):
  PlotAxes[i].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.NullFormatter())
  PlotAxes[i].yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.NullFormatter())
  PlotAxes[i].axis([-25,1025,-25,1025])
  for j in GPlot[i].G.nodes():
    PlotAxes[i].add_artist(Circle((GPlot[i].Position[j][0],GPlot[i].Position[j][1]), GPlot[i].p[j], color='y'))
  nx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes(GPlot[i].G, GPlot[i].Position, node_size=10, node_color=GPlot[i].Color, ax=plt.subplot(1,2,i+1))
  if (GPlot[i].G.edges != []): nx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges(GPlot[i].G, GPlot[i].Position, edge_color = 'black', ax=plt.subplot(1,2,i+1))
  PlotAxes[i].set_aspect(1)
```

What I want: I want the circles to come below and then the graph on top. (the edges on top of the circles layer).

What I get: I don't see the edges in the figure. My guess is it is present below the circles.

A sample data instance.

Here is the data

```
GPlot[0].Components = [[0],[1],[2],[4],[3,5]]
GPlot[0].ActiveStatus = {(0,): 0, (1,): 1, (2,): 0, (4,): 1, (3, 5): 1}
GPlot[0].p = {0: 0.0, 1: 179.5, 2: 0.0, 3: 179.5, 4: 179.5, 5: 179.5}
GPlot[0].Position = {0: [918.476975980191, 566.175809107923], 1: [712.224117254128, 320.20223881946], 3: [136.674359018882, 835.172432802382], 4: [115.261650368544, 74.1499048601371], 5: [1.41743386570314, 502.881853371971]}
GPlot[0].Color = ['black', 'red', 'white', 'white', 'white']

GPlot[1].Components = [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
GPlot[1].ActiveStatus = {(0,): 0, (1,): 0, (2,): 1, (3,): 1, (4,): 1, (5,): 1}
GPlot[1].p = {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 179.5, 3: 179.5, 4: 179.5, 5: 179.5}
GPlot[1].Position = {0: [689.232465921313, 844.969550926396], 2: [942.858050963379, 484.834574765457], 3: [136.674359018882, 835.172432802382], 4: [115.261650368544, 74.1499048601371], 5: [1.41743386570314, 502.881853371971]}
GPlot[1].Color = ['black', 'red', 'white', 'white', 'white']
```

For the graphs do the following:

```
H = nx.path_graph(6)
GPlot[0].G.add_nodes_from(H)
GPlot[0].G.add_edge(3,5)
GPlot[1].G.add_nodes_from(H)
```

I hope this is enough.

Comment: could you provide some example data to initialize `GPlot`? I would like to reproduce your plot. Thanks!

Comment: @MillaWell Is there a way I can mail you the files

Comment: yes, but maybe it would be helpful for others if they accidentally come across this question, that they also can reproduce your code. So is it possible to add a small version of your data, that shows the problem? if not: millawelldev at gmail dot com

Comment: @MillaWell - The data is added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to change the `zorder`, as you can see in this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html).

I'm not familiar with the networkx package, so I don't know how to specify the zorder of the artists it's using to create the drawing of the graph.

Comment: Just to clarify, you tried: `nx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes(GPlot[i].G, ..., zorder=3)`? zorder is not documented as an option, but I'm not sure if it's passed to the underlying objects. Large zorder numbers result in objects coming closer to the foreground.

Comment: Can you try zorder=0 when you create your circle? `PlotAxes[i].add_artist(Circle(..., color='y', zorder=0))`

Comment: It worked. I added zorder=0 only for the circle. Only this worked, the other combinations that I tried did not work. Thanks